# How to disconnect Bluetooth connection as in settings without canceling pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need a way to cancel the Bluetooth connection. For example, click in the settings to disconnect, but do not cancel the pairing

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. My bluetooth device is a input device, BluetoothUtil.INPUT_DEVICE_PROFILE = 4;

```
    private void disconnectToDevice() {
        if (mConnectedDevice != null) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(mContext, new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
                    LogUtil.d("getProfileProxy --> onServiceConnected profile:" + profile + (proxy == null));
                    if (proxy != null) {
                        LogUtil.d(proxy.getClass().getName());
                        BluetoothUtil.disconnectedDevice(mConnectedDevice, proxy);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
                }
            }, BluetoothUtil.INPUT_DEVICE_PROFILE);
        }
    }
```

```
    public static boolean disconnectedDevice(BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothProfile profile) {
        try {
            Method method = profile.getClass().getMethod("disconnect", BluetoothDevice.class);
            method.invoke(profile, device);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtil.d(e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
```